# Limiting prediction range for Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka, prediction

For my research I am using Weka to predict alpha values for different uses. The legal range of alpha is any real number between 0 and 1 inclusive. It is currently performing well, but some of the predictions are greater than 1. I want to keep the classifier as numerical since it is a real number, but I want to limit the range of the prediction to between 0 and 1. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that @Lars-Kotthoff raises interesting points. I would provide my suggestions from a different perspective, ignoring completely the classification problems:

Once you have a set of values within a range [0, inf), you can just try to normalised them using some function such as [logit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) or [min-max](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_min-max_normalization), among others.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in Weka. Whether it will be possible at all will depend on the implementation of the regression algorithm -- I'm not aware of something like this being implemented in any of the algorithms in Weka (although I might be wrong).

Even if it was implemented, the most likely thing that would happen is that everything greater than 1 would simply be replaced by 1. You can do the same thing by checking each prediction and replacing all values greater than 1.

Taking the possible output range into account when training the regression model is unlikely to improve performance.